# Модернизировать php mysql меню

Tags: php, bootstrap, pdo, menu

У меня есть уже готовое меню на чистом php mysql с применением pdo.
Вот как выглядит меню сейчас :

[image: Скриншот меню]

Вот как выглядит база:

[image: Скриншот БД]

Вот php код:

```php
<?php
    // Подключение к базе данных с использованием PDO
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb1';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'ilk889;

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Ошибка подключения к базе данных: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    // Получение данных меню из базы данных
    $menuItems = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM menu_items ORDER BY id")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $menuHtml = '<ul class="menu navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">';
    foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem) {
        $title = $menuItem['title'];
        $link = $menuItem['link'];
        $icon = $menuItem['icon'];

        if ($title === 'Поставщики') {
            $icon = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                     <path d="M6 8a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm2-3a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0zm4 8c0 1-1 1-1 1H1s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4zm-1-.004c-.001-.246-.154-.986-.832-1.664C9.516 10.68 8.289 10 6 10c-2.29 0-3.516.68-4.168 1.332-.678.678-.83 1.418-.832 1.664h10z"/>
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.5 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V7h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H14v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8h-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H13V5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                     </svg>';
        } elseif ($title === 'Клиенты') {
            $icon = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-incognito" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="m4.736 1.968-.892 3.269-.014.058C2.113 5.568 1 6.006 1 6.5 1 7.328 4.134 8 8 8s7-.672 7-1.5c0-.494-1.113-.932-2.83-1.205a1.032 1.032 0 0 0-.014-.058l-.892-3.27c-.146-.533-.698-.849-1.239-.734C9.411 1.363 8.62 1.5 8 1.5c-.62 0-1.411-.136-2.025-.267-.541-.115-1.093.2-1.239.735Zm.015 3.867a.25.25 0 0 1 .274-.224c.9.092 1.91.143 2.975.143a29.58 29.58 0 0 0 2.975-.143.25.25 0 0 1 .05.498c-.918.093-1.944.145-3.025.145s-2.107-.052-3.025-.145a.25.25 0 0 1-.224-.274ZM3.5 10h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-3 0v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm-1.5.5c0-.175.03-.344.085-.5H2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.488 1.312 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 2.024 0A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 10.5 9H14a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-.085c.055.156.085.325.085.5v1a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-5 0v-.14l-.21-.07a2.5 2.5 0 0 0-1.58 0l-.21.07v.14a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-5 0v-1Zm8.5-.5h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-3 0v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Z"/>
                     </svg>';
        } elseif ($title === 'Категории') {
            $icon = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-file-text" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                     <path d="M5 4a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h6a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H5zm-.5 2.5A.5.5 0 0 1 5 6h6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM5 8a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h6a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H5zm0 2a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h3a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H5z"/>
                     <path d="M2 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h8a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm10-1H4a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v12a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h8a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1z"/>
                     </svg>';
        } elseif ($title === 'Товары') {
            $icon = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-shop" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                     <path d="M2.97 1.35A1 1 0 0 1 3.73 1h8.54a1 1 0 0 1 .76.35l2.609 3.044A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 16 5.37v.255a2.375 2.375 0 0 1-4.25 1.458A2.371 2.371 0 0 1 9.875 8 2.37 2.37 0 0 1 8 7.083 2.37 2.37 0 0 1 6.125 8a2.37 2.37 0 0 1-1.875-.917A2.375 2.375 0 0 1 0 5.625V5.37a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 .361-.976l2.61-3.045zm1.78 4.275a1.375 1.375 0 0 0 2.75 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0 1.375 1.375 0 0 0 2.75 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0 1.375 1.375 0 1 0 2.75 0V5.37a.5.5 0 0 0-.12-.325L12.27 2H3.73L1.12 5.045A.5.5 0 0 0 1 5.37v.255a1.375 1.375 0 0 0 2.75 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zM1.5 8.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 9v6h1v-5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h3a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v5h6V9a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v6h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1V9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM4 15h3v-5H4v5zm5-5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-3zm3 0h-2v3h2v-3z"/>
                     </svg>';
        } elseif ($title === 'Закуп') {
            $icon = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cart-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                     <path d="M9 5.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V7H6.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1H8v1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V8h1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H9V5.5z"/>
                     <path d="M.5 1a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h1.11l.401 1.607 1.498 7.985A.5.5 0 0 0 4 12h1a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4h7a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .491-.408l1.5-8A.5.5 0 0 0 14.5 3H2.89l-.405-1.621A.5.5 0 0 0 2 1H.5zm3.915 10L3.102 4h10.796l-1.313 7h-8.17zM6 14a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z"/>
                     </svg>';
        } elseif ($title === 'Ценообразование') {
            $icon = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-coin" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                     <path d="M5.5 9.511c.076.954.83 1.697 2.182 1.785V12h.6v-.709c1.4-.098 2.218-.846 2.218-1.932 0-.987-.626-1.496-1.745-1.76l-.473-.112V5.57c.6.068.982.396 1.074.85h1.052c-.076-.919-.864-1.638-2.126-1.716V4h-.6v.719c-1.195.117-2.01.836-2.01 1.853 0 .9.606 1.472 1.613 1.707l.397.098v2.034c-.615-.093-1.022-.43-1.114-.9H5.5zm2.177-2.166c-.59-.137-.91-.416-.91-.836 0-.47.345-.822.915-.925v1.76h-.005zm.692 1.193c.717.166 1.048.435 1.048.91 0 .542-.412.914-1.135.982V8.518l.087.02z"/>
                     <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                     <path d="M8 13.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 0 11zm0 .5A6 6 0 1 0 8 2a6 6 0 0 0 0 12z"/>
                     </svg>';
        } elseif ($title === 'Склад') {
            $icon = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-box2" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                     <path d="M2.95.4a1 1 0 0 1 .8-.4h8.5a1 1 0 0 1 .8.4l2.85 3.8a.5.5 0 0 1 .1.3V15a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .1-.3L2.95.4ZM7.5 1H3.75L1.5 4h6V1Zm1 0v3h6l-2.25-3H8.5ZM15 5H1v10h14V5Z"/>
                     </svg>';                                                     
        } else {
            $icon = ''; // Пустая строка, если нет иконки
        }

        $menuHtml .= '<li class="nav-item"> <a href="'.$link.'" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" ><span class="svg-icon">'.$icon.'</span> &nbsp; '.$title.'</a></li>';
    }
    $menuHtml .= '</ul>';

   // echo $menuHtml;
?>
```

Вот как выглядит верстка на bootstrap:

```php
<?php include('menu.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dataTables.min/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<header>
 
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.php">Главная</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Переключатель навигации">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              
              <?php echo $menuHtml; ?>

            <form class="d-flex" role="search" >
              <input class="form-control me-2 d-none d-lg-block" type="search" placeholder="Поиск" aria-label="Поиск">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success d-none d-lg-block" type="submit">Поиск</button>
            </form>
            &nbsp; &nbsp;
            &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <div>
              <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="./core/auth/logout.php" role="button">Выйти</a>
              </div>

          </div>
    </div>
</nav>

</header>
<body>
```

Просьба не предлагать mvc laravel и всякие другие фреимворки и шаблонизаторы. Строго php pdo mysql.

### Cуть вопроса:

Хочу добавить подменю. Скажем так, сделать товары родителем, а все, что после него — подкатегориями и так, чтобы иконки оставались. Плюс-минус идеи есть. Но я чувствую, что выбираю самый тяжелый путь ввиду малых знаний.

Проект мой. Учить php начал из-за того, что все вокруг пытались убедить, что то, что мне надо, не получается, но как понял, все ищут легких путей и легкого заработка для себя.

Comment: И все же, в чем конкретно состоит вопрос? В чем проблема с подменю и с иконками? "и так что бы иконки оставались" -- они пропадают куда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимые изменения:

1. Добавить колонку parent, где указывать id родительского пункта меню. После получения списка нужно будет выстроить дерево меню и отрисовывать уже из дерева.
2. Иконки нужно сделать файлами, в колонке icon_path указывать их адреса относительно корня - тогда не нужно будет каждый раз при модификации меню переписывать код.

Comment: Понятно. спасибо. Но иконки нужны именно в свг, но есть идея.

Comment: используйте функцию file_get_contents